# using Authorization laravel in packages

Tags: php, laravel-5

in Laravel Authorization, use from User model but i have a package that use another user authentication (admins). here it is a example of admin facade

```
Auth::guard('panel')->user()
```

when i use Authorization laravel load **user** .

in laravel blade when a user logged in this code work:

```
@can('test')
{{-- expr --}}
<h1>hello</h1>
@endcan
```

but while i login with my admin user of package that code doesn't work.

i was wondering how can i put my user of package in laravel Authorization. some how override on user model.